# Click table row and get value of all cells

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I don't know JQuery, so I'm hoping there is a way to do this in pure Javascript.

I need to click on a table row and get the value of each cell in that row.  Here is the format of my table:

```
<table class='list'>
    <tr>
        <th class='tech'>OCB</th>
        <th class='area'>Area</th>
        <th class='name'>Name</th>
        <th class='cell'>Cell #</th>
        <th class='nick'>Nickname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="somefunction()">
        <td>275</td>
        <td>Layton Installation</td>
        <td>Benjamin Lloyd</td>
        <td>(801) 123-456</td>
        <td>Ben</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there anyway short of putting a unique ID to each cell?

Comment: You could some sort of `for` loop for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no need to add ids or add multiple event handlers to the table. One click event is all that is needed. Also you should use thead and tbody for  your tables to separate the heading from the content.

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
tbody.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var data = [];
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (target) {
        var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    alert(data);
};
```

```html
<table class='list'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='tech'>OCB</th>
            <th class='area'>Area</th>
            <th class='name'>Name</th>
            <th class='cell'>Cell #</th>
            <th class='nick'>Nickname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>275</td>
            <td>Layton Installation</td>
            <td>Benjamin Lloyd</td>
            <td>(801) 123-456</td>
            <td>Ben</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpCWD/

Comment: the only problem with this is that it also gets the html tags in between the <td>

Comment: Well OP's code does not have any tags in it....if that is the case than there is textContent...

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vMLZc/)

**HTML:**

```
<table id="rowCtr" class='list'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='tech'>OCB</th>
            <th class='area'>Area</th>
            <th class='name'>Name</th>
            <th class='cell'>Cell #</th>
            <th class='nick'>Nickname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>275</td>
            <td>Layton Installation</td>
            <td>Benjamin Lloyd</td>
            <td>(801) 123-456</td>
            <td>Ben</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
init();
function init(){

    addRowHandlers('rowCtr');

}

function addRowHandlers(tableId) {
    if(document.getElementById(tableId)!=null){
        var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var ocb = '';
        var area = '';
        var name = '';
        var cell = '';
        var nick = '';
        for ( var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

            rows[i].i = i;
            rows[i].onclick = function() {

                ocb = table.rows[this.i].cells[0].innerHTML;                
                area = table.rows[this.i].cells[1].innerHTML;
                name = table.rows[this.i].cells[2].innerHTML;
                cell = table.rows[this.i].cells[3].innerHTML;
                nick = table.rows[this.i].cells[4].innerHTML;
                alert('ocb: '+ocb+' area: '+area+' name: '+name+' cell: '+cell+' nick: '+nick);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cameron Darlington Please let me know if it satisfied your requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements  = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i =0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   var cell_id = 'id' + i;
   elements[i].setAttribute('id', cell_id);
}
```

Maybe put something like this in function your onclick links to from the `tr`?

Comment: there is no need to add ids to everything.

Comment: @epascarello while that might be true his question says _Is there anyway short of putting a unique ID to each cell?_ I'm merely answering it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    var rowItems = $(this).children('td').map(function () {
        return this.innerHTML;
    }).toArray();
});
```

Comment: This does not return each value from `<td>`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the row's first cell which is clicked according to dataTr.querySelectorAll("td")[0].innerText;

```
document.querySelector("#myTable").addEventListener("click",event => {
    let dataTr = event.target.parentNode;
    let dataRes = dataTr.querySelectorAll("td")[0].innerText;
    console.log(dataRes);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the td cell contents using

```
$("tr").click(function () {
var data= $(this).children("td").map(function(){
                  return $(this).text();
                }).get();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table class='list'>
    <tr>
        <th class='tech'>OCB</th>
        <th class='area'>Area</th>
        <th class='name'>Name</th>
        <th class='cell'>Cell #</th>
        <th class='nick'>Nickname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>275</td>
        <td>Layton Installation</td>
        <td>Benjamin Lloyd</td>
        <td>(801) 123-456</td>
        <td>Ben</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("tr").click(function () {
var data= $(this).children("td").map(function(){
                  return $(this).text();
                }).get();
 // first column of table
    console.log(data[0]); 
     console.log('--------------'); 
    //3rd column
    console.log(data[2]);             
});
    

</script>
</body>
</html>
```