# Get <tr> items form a Table

Tags: javascript, html

I Have this table:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>S.N.</th>
                <th>Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick="mandaDetalle(this.id)">
                <td>PE-6</td>
                <td>John Smith</td>
                <td>GT5</td>
                <td>845254585</td>
                <td>56456456456</td>
                <td>14/07/2017</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

How Can I send onclick that `<tr>` element with the items into a javascript (or jquery) function, I already sending the id of that one `<tr>` but I need to send the items as well, because I need to manipulate them, I need to store each `<th>` into a variable, so I can use them later.

Comment: What do you mean by "send onclick"?

Comment: Almost verbatim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426163/click-table-row-and-get-value-of-all-cells

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click table row and get value of all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426163/click-table-row-and-get-value-of-all-cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

(1) Add an `id` attribute to your row

(2) Attach an `onclick` event listener to the row found by the `id` set previously

(3) Look at the `event.target` to get the clicked table cell

**(Simplified) HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr id="row">
    <td>
      first cell
    </td>
    <td>
      second cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function onRowClick(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
}

document.getElementById('row').addEventListener('click', onRowClick);
```

[Here's the JSFiddle for a demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/gkjd0xp6/) (make sure to open your web console)